# Function not printing value in PYTHON

Tags: python

The Below class and function which use list data to check 
whether word is Palidrome or not, unfortunately i am getting below 
error.

```
class Palid:
    def __init__(self,inp):
        self.inp = inp


    def Palidrome(self):
        mystr = self.inp
        mystr=mystr.casefold()
        revstr = reversed(mystr)
        if list(mystr)==list(revstr):
            print("it is Palidrome")
        else:
            print("No It Is Not")

inp = {'MoM','Dad','TIGER','IS','BACK','TAT'}  
print(Palidrome().inp)
```

am i doing something wrong, or missing wrong. Please share your suggestion
Thanks,

Comment: the class name is Palid not Palidrome, you need to either fix the class name or the call in the bottom of your script

Comment: You should describe the error, `Palindrome` is a function inside the class `Palid`, Its unclear what you're actually trying to do here since you're not calling the class's constructor correctly either.

Comment: "i am getting below error." Where? I can't see any error message in your question. Why are you even trying to use a class for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few clarifications before answering your question

1. Lists in python are represented by square brackets, dictionaries by flower 
   braces.
   In your code, you have written the inp list in flower braces which is wrong.
   The correct representation is

   `inp = ['MoM','Dad','TIGER','IS','BACK','TAT']`
2. You cannot directly call the Palindrome method since you have nested it within the Palid class. You have to instantiate the Palid object and then call the Palindrome class.
3. It is ambiguous if you want to check whether every word in the list is palindrome or not since you're not looping through the list to check if every word is a palindrome.

The correct and simple implementation would be

```
def isPalindrome(inp):
    for word in inp:
        if word[::-1] == word:
            print('{} is a palindrome'.format(word))
        else:
            print('{} is not a palindrome'.format(word))

>>> inp = ['MoM','Dad','TIGER','IS','BACK','TAT']
>>> isPalindrome(inp)
MoM is a palindrome
Dad is not a palindrome
TIGER is not a palindrome
IS is not a palindrome
BACK is not a palindrome
TAT is a palindrome
```

I recommend revising the basics of python.

Comment: Braces are also used for set literals, so `inp = {'MoM','Dad','TIGER','IS','BACK','TAT'} ` is perfectly valid. However, there's no need to use a set there, a tuple or list would be better.

Comment: @Shankar: Thanks a lot, how can we implement it using class and function

Answer (score 1):

You can call function as class.function() .You can see the code

```
class palin:

    def isPalindrome(inp):
        for word in inp:
            if word[::-1] == word:
                print('%s is a palindrome'%word)
            else:
                print('{} is not a palindrome'.format(word))

inp = ['MoM','Dad','TIGER','IS','BACK','TAT']
palin.isPalindrome(inp)
```